# Can I use LM3481 for a system where no-load status can occur?

Tags: boost, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, step-up

I have made a step motor driver board with LM3478 to supply 24v from 12v input.

[image]

[LM3478](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3478.pdf?ts=1592224353152&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

The problem is that a user can power the board without the stepper connected board which drive the board to no-load status on LM3478. Just 2 stepper motor drivers(drv8825) are connected to 24V.

[LM3481](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3481.pdf?ts=1592224395716&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

After LM3478 circuit is broken and burnt, I googled the problem and found LM3478 is not [a proper choice for this situation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/276083/boost-converter-no-load-problem%3E).

It seems like LM3481 might works with the following feature as stated in the datasheet, but I am not sure at all if this is the right one for my situation.

From the first page of the datasheet: "Pulse Skipping at Light Loads"

Will LM3481 work for my situation? If not, what are the other popular chips usable for my system?

Input: 9v~18v

Output: 24v, 1~2A

Comment: Show your schematic as it currently stands.

Comment: I have added the schematic

Comment: Was it the MOSFET that died on low load or the LM3478? Maybe something else? You didn't show the inductor value or type in the schematic. Also what potentiometer did you use?

Answer (score 1):

*This is just an expanded comment and not a direct answer to your question, but all the factors of each component, layout and trace ESL and choice of IC are critical for dynamic motor-loads.*

**General comments.**
Buck regulators are often PWM controlled RLC
Boost Regulators are generally PFM regulated RLC or Flyback Amp-second regulated at constant f.

- The ones which also use Cycle skipping features can handle light loads better.

## Vector Impedance of source, converter and loads

If you understand the impedance ratio effects of a linear transformer for Zin and Zout, then you know that the ideal impedance ratio is the square of the voltage ratio in both directions.  For a boost converter implemented by DCDC, let's call it a non-linear transformer.

To understand how non-linear impedance is measured consider Z(f)= ΔV/ΔI(f) and [see lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksQvMBFx1qY)

Challenge #1 is handling low output loads for the Boost Converter.(explained in link above)

The AC impedance with Capacitor loads on both source and load becomes very low from the ESR. The stability is complex and phase margin/Ripple sensitivity is beyond scope of this answer.  But if you think in terms of Vector Impedance of each element, it helps to understand the variables.

Challenge #2 is Motor Surge current and Back EMF current demand very low ESR, low ESL in Zout of the boost converter.

## Recommendation.

Re-consider if you can choose a Buck regulator from AC that steps down impedance from primary to secondary, you can avoid these complications with dynamic loads and impedance step-up of >4 for a non-linear voltage DC doubler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the LM3481 should do nicely.  The low-load operation is discussed in the 4th paragraph of section 7.1 of your linked datasheet: "Under extremely light load or no-load conditions..." and it does exactly what you're seeking.

However, be aware that you will not be able to achieve a "shut down completely with no load attached" without considerable effort, because there is no way to "sense" that there's no load *unless the circuit is operating* and it looks like the LM3481 will draw about 3.7 mA when operating (see section 6.6 under I_SUPPLY).  However, it will not self-destruct under no-load like the '3478.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! That is actually why I got confused because the 2nd paragraph of section 7.1 in the datasheet of LM3478 states very similar thing about over voltage protection. I don't need to shut down completely. I will be just happy if it does not self destroy when there is no load. I will try out LM3481. Thanks!